# How can turn off VM's in Azure using terraform, if network utilization is less than for 100Kbps for last 1 hour

Tags: azure, terraform

I have many resource group in azure, using terraform **i wanted to get resource group with tag called "Owner" = "myname@xx.com"**

By now i get Resource group, each resource group will have VM. I would like to watch **network utilization(in and out)** for last 1 hours of the VM.

If network utilization is less than 150 kbps for last 1 hours i would like to turn off the VM.

Above all three is possible through terraform? Any guidance would be more useful.

Comment: Terrafrom is used for deployment like Infrastructure as code but the requirement you have is what powershell or cli script offer .. Vm's can't be turned of from terraform unless you use local-exec which will be same as using powershell on your local machine.

Comment: we can get the resource group  with data block but only with the resource group name not the tags  in terraform,  VM can't be turned off using terraform , and network utilization can't be monitored from terraform.. you will have to use log analytics which you can deploy from terraform

Comment: You could do this with a runbook I believe and presumably deploy the runbook via terraform which is presumably what you’re after.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments for my question, i came to know my requirement is not possible through terraform. Still i would expect some interesting input from terraform if possible.

I achieved above requirement by following Azure CLI commands and implemented using python string manipulation. Since i don't wanted to spend money on microsoft services available on azure.

I list out the commands which i used

1. **az vm list -o table** (since i know the interested resource-group, so i easily found VM inside the resource group using python regexp)
2. **az vm monitor metrics tail --name VEL-VM --resource-group Vel_Cluster --aggregation Maximum --metrics "Network In Total"  -o table --offset 2h --interval 15m** (for the same resource i able to see network utilization)
3. Based on threshold condition turned off VM using
   **avm stop  --name VEL-VM --resource-group Vel_Cluster**